# Django - how to obtain all fields from model

Tags: python, django

Is there an easy way to obtain all the fields from a certain django model, **even those set via a foreignkey or many to many field on an other relation**?

Example:

```
class A(models.Model):
    some_number = models.IntegerField()

class B(models.Model):
    link_to_a = models.ForeignKey(A, related_name="link_to_b")
```

Invoking the method for `A` would return `id, some_number, link_to_b`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the semi-documented, non-public API on the `_meta` property of a model class:

```
from myapp.models import A

for f in A._meta._fields():
    print f.name
```

(Note, there is an existing work-item in Django to document this API: http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12663 )

You'll need to manually follow relations, though, and pull in their field names.

Relation fields will have a `rel` property:

```
from myapp.models import A

for f in A._meta._fields():
    print f.name

    if hasattr(f, 'rel'):
        print "Grab more fields from " + rel.to.name
        g in rel.to._meta._fields():
            print g.name
```

Comment: This only returns the model's own fields alas.

Comment: Updated, you can look for "rel" properties on fields to find the related models, and then walk their fields too.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It is useful, but still doesn't solve the problem. The fields of model B are not found as they are not listed in the tree of A's fields (since it's declared on B and not on A).

Comment: If you want to get your hands dirty, check out this code in the Options class that finds reverse relations: http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/options.py#L418

Comment: Around line 421, instead of adding stuff to a cache variable, that's where you'd grab the fields from the reverse relation.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the very undocumented A._meta.fields:

> foreignkeys = [f for f in A._meta.fields if f.attname.endswith('_id')]

The fields have many interesting methods you'll have to discover by using dir() or reading the source...